# How to unzip a folder and delete zipped original?

Tags: php, zip, unzip, delete-file, rights-management

I am creating something like easy installer\setupper for my CMS. When user downloads .zip with my CMS and unpacks it into some folder on his php server he sees a file - install.php and a zip folder named - Contents.zip I need some php function to extract files from that Contents.zip zip file and than delete that file. (If it is possible I want to give different rights to files\folders extracted from there right after folder unZipping)

How to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

you could use [PHP ZipArchive library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) to for you purpose.

also, an [code example from the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php) you might find useful.

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./test112.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

$zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt" . time(), "#1 This is a test string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
$zip->addFromString("testfilephp2.txt" . time(), "#2 This is a test string added as testfilephp2.txt.\n");
$zip->addFile($thisdir . "/too.php","/testfromfile.php");
echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
$zip->close();
?>
```

for changing the file permissions you can use [PHP builtin function chmod.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

for example

```
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0600);
```

to delete the file you can use, [php builtin unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

for example,

```
unlink('test.html');
unlink('testdir');
```

I would strongly recommend yuo to go through the official PHP documentation.

Comment: is that  "PHP ZipArchive library" part of official php 5.2 defalt apache php?

Comment: and where do you delete that zip file?

Comment: @Ole yeah, ZipArchive comes with the official distribution; however it has an external dependency on http://www.zlib.net/

Comment: so it is possible when somebody buys Apache Web Hosting from some provider he will not be able to use this function?